# What is more performant structural directives or using functions within expressions on Angular Templates?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

I was having a discussion with a coworker about different ways of displaying data on Angular Templates (example below shows a case for plural words).

What is best practice when it comes to rendering data from conditionals on Angular Templates? Is it more performant to use structural directives or functions or ternary calls within an expression on Angular templates?

Which out of these 3 scenarios is most efficient?

tickets.component.html

1.

```
<span class="total-text">Total Ticket<ng-container *ngIf="ticketing.inProgressNum !== 1">s</ng-container></span>
```

2.

```
<span class="total-text"> {{ ticketing.inProgressNum !== 1 ? 'Total Tickets' : 'Total Ticket'}} </span>
```

3.

```
<span class="total-text"> {{ getTicketCopy(ticketing.inProgressNum) }} </span>
```

tickets.component.ts

```
getTicketCopy(ticketsInProgress) {
   return ticketsInProgress !== 1 ? 'Total Tickets' : 'Total Ticket'
}
```

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: I would wrap the s at the end in a conditional container

Comment: @AdrianBrand so the 1st one?

Comment: I think a pipe is actually the most performant in this case. Functions and expressions are impure, so they need to evaluate on every change detection cycle. A pipe is pure so it just checks it the input itself changed rather than the underlying condition, and only evaluates if it did change.

Comment: @bryan60 okay great - I'll look into a pipe solution

Comment: I added a pipe solution as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scenario 4 is the most efficient and reusable: a Pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

// import this to / declare this in a module where it will be used
@Pipe({name: 'plural'})
export class PluralPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(str: string, value: number): number {
    return str + ((value !== 1) ? 's' : '');
  }
}
```

then use it just like this:

```
<span class="total-text"> {{ 'Total Ticket' | plural : ticketing.inProgressNum }} </span>
```

pipes exist for simple transforms like this. They're 'pure' which means they only evaluate when the inputs change, plus they're extremely reusable.

as an aside, angular actually has an inbuilt plural directive for complex pluralization cases: https://angular.io/api/common/NgPlural

Answer (score 1):

For appending a single character to the end of a string I would go with no 1 but for something more complicated I would use

```
<ng-container *ngIf="ticketing.inProgressNum !== 1 else multiple">Total Ticket</ng-container>
<ng-template #multiple>Total Tickets</ng-template>
```

It is best practice to not call functions in templates, stick a console.log in one and see how often they are getting hit.

You can also use something like

```
<span class="total-text">{{ticketsText}}</span>
```

and update tickets text when you update the number of tickets. This is by far the most performant method.

Comment: for the second solution, the </ng-conatiner> should be removed

Comment: The closing ng-container shouldn't have been there, it was a cut and pate mistake.